# How was that synth sound made?

Tags: synthesizer

I'm trying to recreate a sound with a virtual synth (Massive, but it could be another one) and can't get quite the same. **Could anyone give me any hint on what kind of sounds are used in that sample ?**

The sample is made of three notes E5, B4, A4.
Zooming on the waveform of note E5, I can see a sequence made of 3 parts, each lasting about 18ms, which seem to be : the note (about 645 Hz), the note + 2 octaves (2659Hz) and the note + 3 octaves (5300 Hz).
See .wav sample here : [.wav sample](https://ufile.io/exgscqjr)
See the zoomed E5 waveform : [Waveform](https://ufile.io/0pyci6d5)

Comment: Welcome! Please take a minute to read about [the topics that are covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You could probably edit this question to be more on-topic (and clearer) by focusing more on the "how" than the "what"—explaining more about the goal you're trying to achieve and what kind of difficulty you're having with it.

Comment: If you managed to re-create a synth sound by visually analyzing a waveform, you’d probably be the first person to do it. You’ll probably want to learn to use your ears for that, not your eyes.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I have to say that I sometimes do that, also with the Fourier transform which, from the distribution of amplitudes and phases relations, gives a first indication of the waveforms to start with.

Comment: @Tom To me a Fourier analysis sounds much more useful. A waterfall plot along with spectral plot would be enough for me to get close, I think.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I agree with that completely. But sometimes, when it looks like a saw, better use a saw as a base and figure things from there ;)

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yes, using my ears has of course been my first try. And I agree with Tom about the fact that seeing an known waveform can help identify the complete synthesis. Unfortunately my ears have not helped me much so far. I've played quite a lot with various combination of parameters and it is because I was still struggling to find the right combination that I thought I might get help from better trained ears.

Comment: @ToddWilcox The spectral analysis hasn't helped me much either. It is tricky to guess which signals the spectrum originated when it is a combination of several signals.